# Как в шаблоне сделать несколько параметров для вызова без перегрузок

Tags: c++

У меня есть шаблон примерно такого вида

```
struct demo {
  template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
  demo(T1&& tipe_1, T2&& tipe_2, T3&& tipe_3) {
   // код который лень повторять
   std::filesysteam::create_directories(tipe_1 / tipe_2);
   // тут тоже код 
  
  }
  // я бы мог сделать так но не хочу повторять много кода из шаблона, но как пример показал
  template <class T1,class T3>
  demo(T1&& tipe_1, T3&& tipe_3) {
   // код который лень повторять
   std::filesysteam::create_directories(tipe_1);
   // тут тоже код 
  
  }
}
```

ну и собственно как я хочу вызывать этот шаблон

```
main () {
// так
demo(tipe_1,tipe_2,tipe_3);
// и так и что бы это было без перегрузок
demo(tipe_1,tipe_3);
}
```

Дополнения, сделал так, пишет ошибку **невозможно преобразовать "initializer list" в demo**

```
template <class T1, class... T2,class T3>
   demo(T1&& tipe_1, T2&&... tipe_2, T3&& tipe_3) {
    // код который лень повторять
    std::filesysteam::create_directories(tipe_1 / tipe_2);
    // тут тоже код 
      
      }
```

Comment: ```class ...T```

Comment: можете показать целиком

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: @Qwertiy понял, а как тогда из    `std::filesysteam::create_directories(tipe_1 / tipe_2);`
сделать так
`std::filesysteam::create_directories(tipe_1);`
надо же условие поставить как то по определению шаблона

Comment: Я понятия не имею, что у тебя там написано. К тому же в первом коде вообще запятые не в тех местах. Присобачь куда-то многоточие.

Comment: @Qwertiy извиняюсь, запятые поправил